# Firebase signInWithCredential returning an error after revoking access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Im my Chrome extension I use chrome.identity.getAuthToken and then Firebase signInWithCredential.  This works fine until I go to accounts.google.com and revoke access to the application.  I would have assumed it would re-prompt me for permission, but the sign in is not working.

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Unsuccessful check authorization response
> from Google: {   "error_description": "Invalid Value" }
> (auth/invalid-credential).
> at _errorWithCustomMessage (index-c6def6da.js:453:1)
> at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index-c6def6da.js:973:1)
> at async _performSignInRequest (index-c6def6da.js:988:1)
> at async _signInWithCredential (index-c6def6da.js:4716:1)

Here's the code I'm using.  Is there somehting I'm missing that's happening when I revoke that access?

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
          
          const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
          signInWithCredential(auth, credential).then((result) => {
           //my code here
              
          }).catch((error) => {

              console.log(error)
          });          
  });
```

**EDIT** So after about 45 minutes, it seems that it's working again.  Like the token had to refresh?  Thoughts?